# Casting string to type it resembles

Tags: c#, casting

I'm trying to determine the best way to transfer a c# type across the network so when it gets to the other side, I can serialize it.

Right now, I am doing this

```
public void Send<T>(T packet) {
            NetworkStream Stream = Server.GetStream();
            byte[] typeName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(typeof(T).FullName);
            byte[] typeLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(typeName.Length);
            byte[] packetdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(packet));
            byte[] length = BitConverter.GetBytes(packetdata.Length);
            Stream.Write(typeLength, 0, 4);
            Stream.Write(typeName, 0, typeName.Length);
            Stream.Write(length, 0, 4);
            Stream.Write(packetdata, 0, packetdata.Length);
        }
```

On the other end I want to do something like this

```
byte[] BufferedData = new byte[0];
while (Alive) {
    byte[] StreamData = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = Client.tcpClient.GetStream().Read(StreamData, 0, StreamData.Length);                                                                    // Read data off the network
    BufferedData = BufferedData.Join(StreamData.Sub(0, bytesRead));                                                                                         // Pull the recieved data out and buffer it
//                  [TypeLength, TypeName, DataLength, Data]
    if (BufferedData.Length > 4) {                                                                                                                          // If the packet length data has been received
        int typeLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(BufferedData);                                                                                                // Gets the first 4 bytes off the data and puts it into the data length int
        if (BufferedData.Length >= typeLength + 8) {                                                                                                        // If the type and the data length of the packet has been received
            int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(BufferedData.Sub(typeLength + 4, 4));                                                                     // Get the data length off the packet
            if (BufferedData.Length >= typeLength + dataLength + 8) {                                                                                       // If the whole packet has been received
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BufferedData.Sub(typeLength + 8, dataLength));                                                        // Get the data as a string

                Type x = Type.GetType(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BufferedData.Sub(4, typeLength)));                                                            // Get the type of the data

->                x obj = (x)JsonSerializer.Deserialize<x>(data);                                                                                                 // This is what i need to figure out

                onReceived.Invoke(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IMistoxPacket>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(BufferedData.Sub(4, dataLength))), new EventArgs());    // Split out packet and send it up
                BufferedData = BufferedData.Sub(dataLength, BufferedData.Length - dataLength);                                                              // Remove the packet from the Buffered data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do i get x to be the type of x instead. so the obj can be the type of x. if that makes since

I don't know if this is a viable path or if there is a better way of doing something like this. I want to send multiple packet types across  the same code and split them out later. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: If you have any properties with a sub-type instance, you'll need to provide type metadata inline. So you might as well use the same mechanism at the top level. Which newtonsoft supports (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm). With System.Text ... no idea.

Comment: `dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, x);`

Comment: That was the best thing since sliced bread. The smallest fix that gave me the most serotonin.